# Can we increase the number of recipients of email in JasperReports Server scheduler?

Tags: email

I have a problem in scheduling a report in JR Server, actually if I try to add the subscribers for a report to send them mail with attached PDF, the maximum number of people I am able to add are 25.

But I have requirement to add 100 people can I increase the limit If yes then please briefly explain how.

I am using JasperReports Server Pro

Please reply asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way of doing this,

Actually Jasperserver Report scheduler provides you space of 1000 characters, in which you can enter the email ids, so that is approx 25-30 depending upon the length,

There are two ways to bypass this:

1. Create batches of Emails and then accordingly create different jobs on scheduler.
2. You can create a email id where in you can add forwarding to a list, and from server you can just send the report to that particular mail

Hope that this helps.